# why the button is not displayed in this simple Swing code in Java?

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

I have very simple Java swing code here, I do not see the button displayed in the frame.
can someone help troubleshoot?

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class HangmanGUI extends JFrame{

        JComboBox favoriteShows;
        JButton[] alphaButtons;
        String infoOnComponent = "";
        JButton button1;

        public static void main(String[] args){

            new HangmanGUI();

        }
        //constructor for Hangman
        /**
         * Instantiates a new hangman gui.
         */
        public HangmanGUI() {

            this.setSize(600,400);

            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            this.setTitle("Play Hangman");

            JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();

            button1 = new JButton("Get Answer");

            thePanel.add(button1);

            this.setVisible(true);


        }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never add `thePanel` to the frame...

```
public HangmanGUI() {

    this.setSize(600,400);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Play Hangman");

    JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
    button1 = new JButton("Get Answer");
    thePanel.add(button1);

    // This is very important ;)        
    add(thePanel);

    this.setVisible(true);

}
```

Personally, I would avoid extending from `JFrame` directory like this.  Apart from the fact that you are not adding any functionality to the frame, it also ties you in to a single deployment/use.

I would start with something like a `JPanel` and build the program up from there, adding this panel to an instance of a `JFrame` create within the "main" entry class...IMHO

Comment: so stupid of me.Thanks!, btw why you do you suggest not to `extend JFrame` like above?

Comment: can you tell by code what you mean by not to `extend JFrame`?

Comment: @user1988876 For a number of reasons.  What if you wanted to use the component?  You can't add top level containers to other contains.  What if you wanted to include the component in another project or redeploy it some other way (like on an applet for example)?  You're also not adding any new functionality to the frame so it's generally considered a waste...

Comment: @user1988876 Instead of doing `public class HangmanGUI extends JFrame{`, you should consider using `public class HangmanGUI extends JPanel {` instead.  This will mean you will need to create an instance of `JFrame` instead, but it's a minor compromise...

Comment: after creating an instance of Jframe, how would I attach Jpanel to the frame? in the constructor itself?

Comment: @user1988876 I wouldn't, that would defeat the purpose.  I would make a "main" class with a `public static void main(String args[])` method and create the instance of the frame and `HagmanGUI` there, adding the panel to the frame as normal...making sure to take care of the [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) issues